# Transitioning Event Handlers from ES5 require pattern to ES6 classes/export pattern?

Tags: node.js, events, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I currently have two bots that uses a bunch of event handlers (from an API and custom) and I'm including them in an index file with require:

bot.js:

```
const Bot = require('telegram-api');
import Emitter from './Emitter';
const bot = new Bot();

Emitter.on('bot_say', (chatId, message) => {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, message, { parse_mode: 'Markdown' })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

bot.on('message', message => {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'hello', { parse_mode: 'Markdown' })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Emitter.js:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const Emitter = new EventEmitter();

export default Emitter;
```

index:

```
require('./bot');
```

I want to change it to es6 style exports/imports so I can do something like

```
export default Bot;
```

and

```
import Bot from './bot';
```

and have the event handlers be running. I can't seem to get it to work properly, the closest I got is to just define them all in the constructor like

```
class Bot {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.on('bot_say', (chatId, message) => {
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, message, { parse_mode: 'Markdown' })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
  }
}
```

which seems messy.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: It's `import Bot from './bot';`.

Comment: Where are `Bot` and `Emitter` defined? Is that your complete "Bot file" (`bot.js`)?

Comment: Transitioning from "event handlers" to "classes" makes no sense. Those are totally orthogonal. Keep your design.

Comment: @Bergi I fixed the import, thanks. I was writing them up from scratch. My files are huge I'm not going to post them. `Bot` in the original version is defined in the library. `const Bot = require('telegram-api');` Emitter is just my own file that I can add to this question. I understand the title might be confusing but I hope you can see that I'm trying to figure out how to transition Event handlers from a pattern that uses require to a pattern that uses es6 imports.

Comment: I don't see what this transition has to do with event handlers. You just change `module.exports` to an `export` declaration and `require`s to `import` declarations. The rest of the code should stay the same. Can you post your whole app or is it too large?

Comment: The difference is that I don't have to do module.exports the way it is currently. I just do `require('bot');` and it injects all the code and all the vent handlers are ready. I want to encapsulate the entire file in a class and do an import but I can't just wrap it in a class declaration because that's not how classes work. If I declare functions they will just sit there until called.

Comment: If you don't have any exports, then just don't use an `export` declaration. You can still `import 'bot';` and it loads the module and all event handlers are ready. If you want to use the initialisation code later or multiple times or something, use a plain function that can be called not a `class` that constructs an object.

Comment: Awesome! That is great information actually. I would still like to know how to build a class that contains a ton of event handlers though.

Comment: Well you could place them in the constructor, but it would be much better to put them in a static method that creates the instance and then sets up the handlers as a side effect.